# Concise way of checking if one of two values is null while the other isn't

Tags: c#

Sometimes I need to verify that out of two values, one **is** null while the other **isn't**. This works:

`(a != null && b == null) || (a == null && b != null)`

But it becomes cluttered when the variable names are longer, like nested properties on an object. Creating a helper function is a good option for this, but is there a more concise syntax for writing it inline?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
(a == null) != (b == null)
```

Note that if operator == is overriden for you class, you can have problem.
The following does not use operator ==

```
object.ReferenceEquals(a, null) == object.ReferenceEquals(b, null)
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! And thanks for pointing out the potential issue with operator overloading, good to keep in mind!